# Subset String Array based on length

Tags: string, julia

I have a vector with > 30000 words. I want to create a subset of this vector which contains only those words whose length is greater than 5. What is the best way to achieve this?

Basically df contains mutiple sentences.

So,

```
wordlist = df2;
wordlist = [strip(wordlist[i]) for i in [1:length(wordlist)]];
```

Now, I need to subset wordlist so that it contains only those words whose length is greater than 5.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some example code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sub(A,find(x->length(x)>5,A)) # => creates a view (most efficient way to make a subset)
```

EDIT: `getindex()` returns a copy of desired elements

```
getindex(A,find(x->length(x)>5,A)) # => makes a copy
```

Comment: It is returning an error, sub has no method matching sub(::Array{Any,1},::Array{Int64,1})

I used the following syntax,
wordlist2 = sub(wordlist,find(x -> length(x)>4,wordlist));

Comment: Got it! Used getindex instead of sub.

Comment: getindex() give you a copy, but sub() creates a view, both have the same syntax. above code works for me (VERSION # => v"0.4.0-rc2")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```
wordlist = filter(x->islenatleast(x,6),wordlist)
```

and combine it with a fast condition such as `islenatleast` defined as:

```
function islenatleast(s,l)
    if sizeof(s)<l return false end
    # assumes each char takes at least a byte
    l==0 && return true
    p=1
    i=0
    while i<l
        if p>sizeof(s) return false end
        p = nextind(s,p)
        i += 1
    end
    return true
end
```

According to my timings `islenatleast` is faster than calculating the whole length (in some conditions). Additionally, this shows the strength of Julia, by defining a primitive competitive with the core function `length`.

But doing:

```
wordlist = filter(x->length(x)>5,wordlist)
```

will also do.